# Hibernate collection bi-directional mapping

Tags: hibernate, collections, mapping, reverse

I have three tables **user, product, user_product** and the relationship is **user(1):product(n)** and the user pojo contains a list of products and product pojo contains a user.

```
 Class User{
        List<Product>;
 }

 Class Product{
     User;
 }
```

User.hbm.xml

```
   <bag name="products" table="user_product" cascade="all" >
        <key>
            <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="Product">
            <column name="product_id" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </bag>
```

Product.hbm.xml

```
   <join table="user_product"  optional="true">
       <key column="product_id" />
       <many-to-one name="user" column="user_id" cascade="none"  />
    </join>
```

The mapping file of user contains list of products mapped using **bag**. The problem is that now I have to migrate large amount of data from some legacy application, so whenever to add a product with user relation, I have to fetch the user and list of his products and add the new product and update the user, this results in lot of insert statements. So I created the product pojo with user detail and the user mapping is done using **join tag**. I thought this way I can add only a single product with user relation, but when I save a product it deletes the entries from **user_product** using **user_id** and then inserts the new value thus removing all the previous products of the user. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If it is one to many relationship, why you need user_product table. You can achieve the relationship using use and product table only.

Comment: @javafan I know that and this was done by some one else and I cannot change that.